# NetLogo: Turtles aren't "infecting" each other

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a simulation about herd immunity. For this to happen, I have to code a virus that infects turtles. Here's the code so far:

```
to setup
ask n-of (sick-turtles / 5) turtles with [color != red]
[set sick? true]


 ask turtles
[
if sick? = true
[
  set color green
]
]

ask turtles
[if color != red
[set immune? 1]
]

ask turtles 
[if color != green
[set sick? 1]
]
end

to go
if smallpox = 0
[
set infection-rate 99
set infectivity 6
set lethality 0
set recovery recovery-rate
set immunity (1 - (1 / infectivity)) * 100
]

to infect
ask turtles with [not immune? and not sick?]
[if any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [sick? = true] 
[if (random 100) < infection-rate
  [set sick? true]
]
]
end
```

However, the turtles aren't infecting each other at all. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a couple of general coding comments first (1) In your setup, you have code like `ask turtles [ if condition [ do something ] ]`. It is much easier to read if you write that as `ask turtles with [ condition ][do something]`. (2) The `go` procedure doesn't have an `end`. (3) You seem to be switching between using true/false and using 1/0 as a flag - you should always use true/false so that you can use `if sick?` or `if not sick?` instead of `if sick = true` and `if sick != true`. This may be the cause of your problem - you are setting `sick?` to true in setup, but to 1 later on in setup.

Comment: JenB is exactly right. Additionally, however, you're not actually recoloring the newly infected turtles, so it may just *look* like the infection isn't spreading. So, make sure to set the turtles' color when you set `sick?` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you, for both solving the problem and giving me pointers on how to make my code "sleeker". Cheers!